# AppWarp multiplayer tutorial for libGDX

Tags: android, android-studio, libgdx, appwarp

I'm looking for some up to date tutorial for AppWarp libGDX integration. I think, this is a bit deprecated: http://appwarp.shephertz.com/game-development-center/java-multiplayer-libgdx-tutorial

I know the basic concepts, that I need `AppWarp client` and three other adapters and already have created an app and a room in `App42 Management Console`, but don't know how to import `AppWarp SDK` to Android Studio. I have a perfectly working single player application, but get stuck in details and integration process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android Studio you need to add App42MultiPlayerGamingSDK as a dependency in build.gardle file. You can use following code snippet in which libs folder contains the SDK library.

dependencies {

```
compile files('libs/App42MultiPlayerGamingSDK.jar')
```

}

Comment: Where should I place the `jar` file in project to avoid `Gradle` errors?